# Create branch without some commits

Tags: git, gitkraken

I have situation described in the image below.
I want to create new branch that will exclude commits 1 & 2,
and will consist commits 4 & 3.

[image]

Comment: `git checkout -b new_branch_name actual_master_commit;git cherry-pick 3 4`. Solution 2, `git checkout -b new_branch_name 4;git revert 2 1 --no-edit`.

Comment: @ElpieKay the cherrypick 3,4 includes all the changes of 1,2 how exactly this going to work?

Comment: No, they shouldn't. Do you encounter a conflict when cherry-picking 3 and 4?

Comment: The second approach works well thanks.you can add it as answer, When i cherry pick some commit(3 or 4) it is already contains all his parents (1-2).
I my case i want completely ignore changes done in 1 and 2

Comment: `git-cherry-pick` works with diff only. So `git cherry-pick 3` applies the diff between 2 and 3, not including the diff between 2 and its parent 1.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the tree goes **4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1**, that is, `4` is the oldest commit, and `1` the newest. If so,

```
git checkout -b new_branch <commit-hash-of-3>
```

However, if the tree goes in the opposite direction, you will create a copy of your branch at commit `4` (tree is **1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4**), and [revert](https://devdocs.io/git/git-revert) the changes made in the old commits 1 and 2.

```
git checkout -b new_branch <hash-of-4>
git revert <hash-1> <hash-2>
```

Another solution would be to checkout to the newest commit before `1` and [rebase](https://devdocs.io/git/git-rebase) on top of this.

```
git checkout -b new_branch <hash-of-1>^
git rebase -i <hash-of-4>
```

and in the editor, just drop the commits for 1 and 2. (This is similar to cherry picking)

---

For more reading purposes, do look at [git scm page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).